# "The application has failed to start because cxcore210.dll was not found". Why would this happen?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I'm having trouble running basic opencv scripts on my new machine.  I've installed opencv2.1.  I am linking these files from the linker:

> C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\cv210.lib
>   C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\cvaux210.lib
>   C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\cxcore210.lib
>   C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\highgui210.lib

I run the program, it compiles.  However, it gives me the error stated above.  Why is that?  I tried linking to the dll it describes, and it doesn't like that either.

Comment: Is there a `cxcore210.dll` in the same directory where the application's executable is located?

Comment: No.  But I figured I could just link to it, rather than copy and paste cxcore210.dll to that directory..

Comment: Those .lib files are just import libraries:  you link against them and they wrap the calling `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` and other related DLL functions so that you don't have to do that explicitly in your code.  You still need to have the DLL available at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

The DLL needs to be somewhere in the [DLL search path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(VS.100).aspx), otherwise the loader won't be able to find it.

The two easiest options are to copy the DLL(s) to the directory in which your executable is located or the directory from which you are running your executable, or to add the directory in which the DLL(s) are located to the PATH.

Comment: Adding the directory to the PATH sounds ideal, but that doesn't seem to be working.  I've added the opencv/bin directory to the path from environment variables and no dice..

Comment: @tomas:  After adding to the path you may need to restart Visual Studio, log out and and log back in, or reboot; I've forgotten what the rules are concerning when the environment block is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

this video will help you..

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nPpa_WiArI

Or else I came up with another solution  just copy the dll files directly into  C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder (this is my system folder). This helped me and my code was executed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

I configure correctly the properties of my project, like 100 tutorials says: But never work, so i try copy the dll to the application directory and works. I dont know why the linker dont see the dlls

I just copy the cv210.lib ,cvaux210.lib, cxcore210.lib ,highgui210.lib